# Compute data for join only once in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I am writing a large query with many joins. Midway through the query the result rows look somewhat like this:

| x1 | y1 | z1 |
| x2 | y2 | z2 |
| x3 | y3 | z3 |
| x4 | y4 | z1 |

I go on to join other tables to this set of rows but the joins are dependent *only* on the z-column (the data I wish to join to each row is identical if the z value is identical). Since there are duplicates in the z column (like z1) I do not wish to duplicate this work. Is it possible to calculate the data to join only once?

My current SQL query looks something like this, assuming t1 represents the rows as above:

```
select *
from
t1
join t2 on t2.propertyA = t1.z
join t3 on t3.propertyB = t2.propertyB
...
```

If I can do this in a single SQL query this would be ideal. With the current duplication of effort the query I'm running is not performant enough. Nested queries are okay.

Comment: So which of the 2 rows with z1 will be joined to the other tables and why?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can arbitrarily choose one `z` row for the join;

```
select *
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by z order by x) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1
     t2
     on t2.propertyA = t1.z and t1.seqnum = 1 . . .
```